# R - Extract Specific Rows in Dataset And Save Into New Dataframes

Tags: r, regex, sorting, merge, dataset

I'm looking to sort/process some large data before I enter it into a function.

I have a large dataset of log readings, consisting of many unique addresses and timings.

The data looks a bit like this:

```
UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:01
UNIQUE_ADDRESS2 24/08/2016 13:02
UNIQUE_ADDRESS3 24/08/2016 13:05
UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 25/08/2016 00:00
UNIQUE_ADDRESS2 25/08/2016 00:01
UNIQUE_ADDRESS3 25/08/2016 00:12
```

I am ultimately running a function that needs individual data frames consisting of a specific unique address and a specific date only.

The data frame will look like this, consisting of all rows which contain the specific unique address AND specific date.

```
dataframe1 <- [UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:01, 
UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:03, 
UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:06, 
UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:08
... etc]
```

Where there will be a dataframe2 which corresponds to UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 again, but with all the timings within the date of 25/08/2016 instead. This will be done for each device.

I figured this needs to be done in a loop, but I can't get the syntax done correctly.

So far I am using grep to extract each unique address from the massive log file, like this, to create data frames with each device separately:

```
device1 <- logfile[grep("^UNIQUE_ADDRESS1", logfile[,2]), ]
```

Then I have created an array of dates:

```
dates <- c("23/09/2016", "24/08/2016", "25/08/2016")
```

I now want to create new data frames that combine each individual unique addresses and each date. So all the log readings for UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 on date 23/09/2016 in one data frame, then another for 24/08/2016, etc. The same for each UNIQUE_ADDRESS.

I've tried using grep and grepl, but when I have used them in an if loop or ifelse loop they claim that my dates are not in my device data frames (which they definitely are), and any value I try, it returns false no matter what.

Can anybody help me with how I can achieve my aim?

Thanks

**Edit**

At the moment I'm trying to do this in a for loop, where "device1" contains the unique addresses for device 1, etc. However, when I increment *i* it'll only save to the same data fame (device1) instead of a new dataframe which is what I need.

```
for (k in 1:6)

device1 <- device1[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device2 <- device2[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device3 <- device3[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device4 <- device4[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device5 <- device5[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device6 <- device6[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device7 <- device7[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
device8 <- device8[grep(dates[i], device1[,4]), ]
```

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data so that it's reproducible. BTW the 2nd code block is not valid R code.

Comment: @Hack-R the data is confidential as it's from a study unfortunately, the second block was just quick pseudocode to demonstrate what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have your input data in a data frame, e.g.

```
> myTable
             Var1       Var2  Var3
1 UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:01  
2 UNIQUE_ADDRESS2 24/08/2016 13:02
3 UNIQUE_ADDRESS3 24/08/2016 13:05
4 UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 25/08/2016  0:00
5 UNIQUE_ADDRESS2 25/08/2016  0:01
6 UNIQUE_ADDRESS3 25/08/2016  0:12
```

Consider using the dlply function of the R-package plyr.

```
library(plyr)
myList = dlply(aTable, ~ Var1 + Var2, .fun = identity)
```

Each element of the list myList will be one of your sub-tables, e.g.

```
> myList[[1]]
         Var1       Var2  Var3
1 UNIQUE_ADDRESS1 24/08/2016 13:01
```